# Finding the mass of pure matter

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mass, spacetime, mass-energy

How would I find the mass of "pure" matter, that is, non-quantized matter, for a given volume?Let's say I have a volume equal to 1 meter squared, and I completely filled it up with matter - that is, no space in between. What would be it's mass?

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no idea what you mean. And I'm pretty sure 1 meter squared is a surface. ;-)

Comment: 1 meter cubed, ach. I mean, matter that isn't made up of particles, there is no space inbetween. "PURE" matter

Comment: What do you mean "not made up of particles"? Let's start here: what is *matter* to you?

Comment: Anything that takes up space and has mass. I mean, something theoretically not made up of particles. A volume of 1 meter cubed that is completely filled with pure matter - no particles, just matter - would have a mass of what?

Comment: Everything with mass is made up of atomic particles. Your "pure" matter does not exist.

Comment: I suppose if you ever found this "pure" matter, you would put it on a balance to find its mass. Just like ordinary, "impure" matter.

Comment: So this pure matter could be another fundamental particle where the theory predicts a mass but also (for some reason) the theory predicts that the mass must have a set, rather large volume. It would either be the least dense particle in existence or it would be a black hole seed particle or it would be massless and travel at light speed. In either of the first two cases, it is impossible to tell you its mass.

Comment: Just in case it helps to clarify, my reading of this question is the following. Trace perhaps you could confirm if this is correct. Are you assuming that the different elementary particles (e.g. electrons or protons) have different masses because, say, the proton is physically larger than the electron? In which case, the density of "pure matter" $\rho$ would be given by the equation $\rho = \frac{\mathrm{mass\, of\, proton}}{\mathrm{volume\, of\, proton}}$. This idea is at odds with our current understanding of elementary particles, for which this concept of a volume is basically meaningless.

Answer (score 3):

Are you thinking of something like [neutronium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutronium)? This is the (hypothetical) matter formed when you compress the electrons into the protons to make neutrons, then pack the neutrons tightly together. If so, then the density is $4 \times 10^{17}$ kg/m$^3$.

However you should note that even neutronium isn't pure matter, because neutrons are made up from quarks and there is free space inside the neutron between the quarks. There have been suggestions that if you compress neutronium you could collapse if further to make [strange matter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strange_matter) with a density that is about 100 times higher still. However this is currently only speculative.

By coincidence a paper on this subject has just appeared on the Arxiv: [Properties of High-Density Matter in Neutron Stars](http://arxiv.org/abs/1408.0079)

Answer (score 3):

Suppose classical "pure matter" as you describe it existed and suppose a spherical volume $V$ of $1\,\text{m}^3$ of this stuff has mass $M$. Since it exists of pure matter only, one expects a uniform mass density $\rho$ and $M$ is just $\rho V$. So you'd have to define the mass density of "pure matter" to answer your question.

Say you make it 1 Planck mass per Planck length cubed, a [natural](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units) density to assume for your hypothetical pure matter:

$$\rho_P = \frac{m_P}{{l_P}^3} = 5.15500\times10^{96}\,\text{kg}\,\text{m}^{-3}.$$

Now, that's [*heavy* stuff](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/139301/cosmology/27607/Superunification-and-the-Planck-era#ref1070087).

Comment: @celtschk and the people who voted earlier: I've edited my answer. I can't comment more on the implications of having a Planck density right now, but sufficit to say this is quantum gravity territory.

Comment: I've deleted my comment, since it no longer applies to the current version of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not a cosmologist but there some interstellar objects known as neutron stars that are extremely dense. Some neutron stars can have masses of 500,000 times that of earth with a diameter of about 25km. In the core of these stars, it is hypothesized that "quark liquid" exist which is when quarks get pushed into each other with no spacing between them. In such a way as a traditional nucleus has protons and neutrons conjoined. This result in extremely dense matter. A teaspoon of this type of matter could be equivalent to the weight of mountains here on earth

Comment: Interesting, but would be improved with links and references.